# How to write a script as a string and save it in variable ten echo it to any file during run time and execute it in a terminal

Tags: 12.04, bash

Here u are the code i want to do , the problem is the special characters i punt like / and then  and those things while executing , it dont consider the text between those two parentheses () a string to save it in a variable and that is all so how can i fox this 
 i put the whole code to give u a clear idea about the problem 
Thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/bash 

trap "echo 'Caught' >/home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/fsg.txt" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP


script=( #!/bin/bash 
echo "fdsfds"
while sleep 4
do
i=0
while read line
do
if [ -n "$line" ] && ["$line" != "separator"] 
then
programeNameAndPID[i]=$line
((i++))
elif [["$line" == "separator"]] ; then
getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram=$( ps -e | grep "$programeNameAndPID[0]" | awk '{print $1;}')
if [${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]} -gt ${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2  ]
then
unset gnomeTab
newProcessNumber=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2
index=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-1
for (( c=$newProcessNumber ; c > 0 ; c-- ))
do
gnomeTab+=( --tab -e "cpulimit -p $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[$index] -l $programeNameAndPID[1] ") 
((index--)) 
done
gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
fi
i=0
unset programeNameAndPID
fi
done < $dataFile
done)
echo -e $script > /home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/script.txt
gnome-terminal -e " /home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/script.txt"
```

**also i tried this part of code to store the text in file directly and i found taht the stored is the run resut of the code not just considered a string and just write it in file as i want**

```
cat > /home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/script.sh << EOF 
#!/bin/bash 
echo "fdsfds"
while sleep 4
do
i=0
while read line
do
if [ -n "$line" ] && ["$line" != "separator"] 
then
programeNameAndPID[i]=$line
((i++))
elif [["$line" == "separator"]] ; then
getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram=$( ps -e | grep "$programeNameAndPID[0]" | awk '{print $1;}')
if [${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]} -gt ${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2  ]
then
unset gnomeTab
newProcessNumber=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2
index=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-1
for (( c=$newProcessNumber ; c > 0 ; c-- ))
do
gnomeTab+=( --tab -e "cpulimit -p $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[$index] -l $programeNameAndPID[1] ") 
((index--)) 
done
gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
fi
i=0
unset programeNameAndPID
fi
done < $dataFile
done
EOF
```

Comment: `data=\`cat <<EOF line1 line2 (...) lineN EOF\``?

Comment: Why dont you store the actual contents in `/home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/script.txt` itself

Comment: ok i already tried it i will edit the question to see what i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the main problem in both cases is that the `$variables` will be expanded before you want. Try

```
script=$(cat <<'END_OF_SCRIPT'
# your script goes here. 
END_OF_SCRIPT
)
```

The single quotes on the first `END_OF_SCRIPT` essentially single-quote the entire here-document.

Next, it is highly important to quote `$script` whenever you use it:

```
echo "$script" > some_file
```

Otherwise all sequences of whitespace, including newlines, will be collapsed to a single space.

Comment: Thank u sir really it works wonderfully  :) and yes u are right the problem was that he writes the valus of the $variable instead of just write the text as if it is plain text in the file , but i wonder how just the ' ' single quote of the first 'EOF' solved the problem _ more explanation pls :)

Comment: See the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: thank u but in belong to <<- and the leading tabs i tried it and all the tabs in the input lines appeared in the file script.sh and they say over there that it will be stripped so ? any explanation

Comment: make sure they are actual tab characters and not spaces. the manual is specific about that.

Comment: they mean that right "\t"?